# Can't find C/C++ extension in VS Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, archlinux

I'm trying to install the C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code, but I can't find it in the extensions list. I'm running Arch Linux, but the [extension website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) says it's crossplatform.

I also tried running `ext install ms-vscode.cpptools` to no avail.

Any idea why it might be missing/how to get it?

edit: I downloaded the .vsix extension bundle, and manually installed it and it seems to work. Any idea why it was missing in the extensions list?

Answer (score 6):

### Why this happens

This is caused because VS Code is released in two flavors. The base version, known as **Code OSS** has an open-source license, and the other, known as **Visual Studio Code**, includes some proprietary Microsoft code, and so it's released under a proprietary license.

Arch Linux's package repository, which only provides open-source software, uses the **Code OSS** flavor, which is not permitted to access the VS Marketplace due to restrictions placed by Microsoft (see [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code#Extensions_support))

### Solution

**Option 1 (recommended):** Go to the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), search for the extension, then click "Version history" and download the latest version. You can then install the `.vsix` file on VS Code as shown below

[image: How to install VSIX file in VS Code]

**Option 2 (based on [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107997#issuecomment-703245178)):** Install the proprietary version instead by downloading the `tar` from the [VS Code download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads), then install it by running `pacman -U code-stable-x64-xxxxxxxxxx.tar.gz`, replacing the file name with yours of course.

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux [disables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code) the VS Marketplace in its version, because it thinks it's not allowed to use it. The marketplace you are seeing is a different one.

The way around this problem is to get VS Code [directly](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) from the manufacturer (On Arch, just unpack the `tar.gz` and run `bin/code`)